# How to use php preg_replace to replace HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to change `<pre>` with `<code>` and `</pre>` with `</code>`.

I'm having problem with the slash / and regex.

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to parse HTML with regex, but for this simple example, I suppose it couldn't hurt.

Comment: I'm modifying a wordpress plug-in and this is the way they do it.

Comment: I agree that it's fine for this example. Was just giving a heads up about deeper complexities.

Comment: As admirable WordPress the application is at meeting its goals, never assume *anything* related to the WordPress codebase is a good general example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just use str_replace:

```
$str = str_replace(array('<pre>', '</pre>'), array('<code>', '</code>'), $str);
```

If you feel compelled to use regexp:

```
$str = preg_replace("~<(/)?pre>~", "<\\1code>", $str);
```

If you want to replace them separately:

```
$str = preg_replace("~<pre>~", '<code>', $str);
$str = preg_replace("~</pre>~", '</code>', $str);
```

You just need to escape that slash.

Comment: Could you show the preg_replace splited in 2 sentences, one per tag? Thanks

Comment: @NullUserException What if there were attributes mentioned in the `<pre>` tag and you had to retain them exactly as they are and just replace the `<pre` part of it? For example, how would you change `<span style="padding: 10px;">Test</span>` to `<div style="padding: 10px;">Test</div>` ?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to escape the /s with \s, or use a different delimiter for the expression.

Instead, though, how about using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? `<pre>` and `</pre>` will be easy to match as they're not likely to contain any classnames or other attributes.

```
$text=str_replace('<pre>','<code>',$text);
$text=str_replace('</pre>','</code>',$text);
```

Comment: What if there were attributes mentioned in the `<pre>` tag and you had to retain them exactly as they are and just replace the `<pre` part of it? For example, how would you change `<span style="padding: 10px;">Test</span>` to `<div style="padding: 10px;">Test</div>` ?

Comment: You just replace '<span' with '<div' and '</span>' with '<\div>'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew I could do that, but what wanted to find out how to tackle this case when I have an occurrence of the <span> tag within my body content. Because the replace will replace all occurrences and I need to replace only the class names and not all occurrences. How do I go about this?

Comment: You mean, only spans that have a certain class attribute? You'll need to use a regex. I suggest to post a new question or search for previous ones that use regex.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very  easy solution to replace multiple words in a string :

```
<?php
 $str="<pre>Hello world!</pre>";


$pattern=array();
$pattern[0]="/<pre>/";
$pattern[1]="/<\/pre>/";


$replacement=array();
$replacement[0]="<code>";
$replacement[1]="</code>";

echo preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str);?>
```

**output :**

```
 <code>Hello world!</code>
```

With this script you can replace as many words in a string as you want :

just place the word (that you want to replace) in the pattern array , eg :

```
     $pattern[0]="/replaceme/";
```

and place the characters (that will be used in place of the replaced characters) in the replacement array, eg :

```
      $replacement[0]="new_word";
```

Happy coding!