# HTML search that will match phrases with formatting

Tags: php, replace

I need to modify HTML markup such that a matched word or phrase gets hightlighted, but that phrase may contain markup. For example:

This **f*or*mat**ted text :

```
This <b>f<i>or</i>mat</b>ted text
```

I'd want to be able to find "This formatted" and wrap it in  `<style="color:lightblue" </span>` tags

So the above would become:

```
 <span  style="color:yellow">This <b>f<i>or</i>mat</b>ted</span> text
```

I'm using PHP on linux.

Thanks

EDIT:
I'm not looking to replace tag but match text that has tags within it. Basically matching a string that may be spaced out with arbitrary tags of any type or length.
Please ignore my ancient html tags, they were just easier to type.

Comment: possible duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376051/how-to-use-php-preg-replace-to-replace-html-tags

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, I don't want to find and replace tags, like the other post, I want to find a phrase that has tags within it and highlight the entire phrase without affecting the tags already in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to find the specified string, then replace it with a version surrounded by your tag.

Comment: I'm not strong with regex, but everything I could find indicated that using regex to search HTML won't work. Can you show me how I could use preg_match to find a phrase that has arbitrary tags interspersed in it?

Comment: That depends on how you're looking to use it. Is this meant to search an entire page, or just sections of it? Does it need to be done once when the page loads, or dynamically each time the user clicks/enters text?

Comment: I'm am searching HTML snippets and displaying the highlighted version, not dynamic.

Comment: You could do this (assuming you're searching for `foo`):  
    
    <?php  
    $input = <HTML snippet>  
    $pattern = "/(f(<.*?>)*?o(<.*?>)*?o(<.*?>)*?)/"  
    $replacement = "<span class='highlight'>\1</span>  
    preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$input)`

Comment: That does it. I'll just have to derive the regex patter from the search phrase, thanks!