# PHP, Please help to improve Regular Expression

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP, preg_replace, replace tag with tag attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456272/php-preg-replace-replace-tag-with-tag-attr)

I read many references but this is very hard to understand.

Please help to improve my code.

I want to replace

```
<script src="core.js"></script> to <temp src="core.js"></temp>
```

While I am testing it, below will actual output what I want. However, on $replace, I only put `<temp`, how come it could replace the end tag???

```
$string = '<script src="core.js"></script>';
$pattern = '/^<script|<\/script>$/i';
  //    ^(start from script)    | (or)    $(end with script)
$replace = '<temp';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Out Put

```
<temp src="core.js"></temp>
```

Thank you very much for your help and advice.

Comment: str_replace() http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php ?

Comment: What sense has this? You're making your valid code invalid. Seems more like a structural/design problem than a real world problem.

Comment: I dont very understand regular expression...Please tell me which part is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question because you asked about regex, but if you can use str_replace, its generally better to do so, and much quicker.

```
$result = str_replace('<script', '<temp', $string);
$result = str_replace('script>', 'temp>', $result);
```

The problem with this though is, it wont match strings like:

```
<script src="core.js"></script >
```

The reason i didn't just do:

```
str_replace("script", "temp", $string);
```

is because you could have other mensions of the word "script" in your variable, for example if a js file was called example.script.js

Comment: I am a noob, May I ask in this situation, usually people do not use regular expression?

Comment: Correct; as Jleagle says it is much quicker to use str_replace for simple replacements.  The [PHP manual for str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) states "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace()."

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use a regex?  Can you not just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
$string = '<script src="core.js"></script>';
echo str_replace("script", "temp", $string);
```

**EDIT**

If you feel you really must use a regex, then the problem you're having is the end tag `</script>` is being replaced with just `<temp`.  Try using capturing parentheses:

```
$string = '<script src="core.js"></script>';
$pattern = '/(<\/?)script([^>]*>)$/i';
$replace = '$1temp$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

The pattern here can be read as:

- `(<\/?)`: A `<` optionally followed by a `/`
- `script`: The literal string `script`
- `([^>]*>)`: Any character that is not a `>` 0 or more times, followed by a `>`

In the replacement string, `$1` means whatever matched the first parenthesised pattern, and $2 the second.

Comment: On actually implement, $string is not just that html. I need to find and replace..if so, there will have chance have similar word same as 'script'....how can I avoid this issue?