# How to replace entire string including html tags?

Tags: php, html, string

i am getting the following HTML from a textbox in laravel:

```
<p>Just a test</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Just a test</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Just a test</p>
```

Basically what i want to do is just remove all the `&nbsp;` and also all the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` , i am aware that using regex's to filter HTML is a bad idea , but in my case the scenario is limited to just there 2 options i mentioned above.

So i have the below PHP code:

```
$replaceNbsp = array('&nbsp' , '&nbsp;' , '<p>&nbsp;</p>' );
$blog_content = str_replace($replaceNbsp , ' ' , $request->blog_content);
return $blog_content;
```

But now intsead of removing the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` completely , i get the below output.

```
<p>Just a test</p>
<p> ;</p>
<p>Just a test</p>
<p> ;</p>
<p>Just a test</p>
```

How do i replace the HTML in the description too ??

Comment: first, you are not using regex. Second, what's wrong with regex?

Comment: It replaces in the order you supplied; reverse it

Comment: Try reversing the order of those elements in your $replaceNbsp -- you remove the big ones first then the little ones.

Comment: @nogad thanks that worked !! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use php preg\_replace to replace HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376051/how-to-use-php-preg-replace-to-replace-html-tags)

Comment: @aimme disagree that it's a duplicate. regex/replacement questions are often nuanced and depend both on the content being searched and the replacement being performed.

Comment: @S.Imp its exactly not same, but in my opinion its a possible duplicate. compare the answers too.

Comment: @aimme You are of course entitled to your opinion but I had compared the two posts and that is what prompted my prior comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, there's nothing wrong with regular expressions:

```
$blog_content = preg_replace( '/<p>(&nbsp;)?<\/p>/g', '', $request->blog_content );
```

To stick with your original strategy, you need to reverse the order in the array to be order from most specific to least specific:

```
$replaceNbsp = array( '<p>&nbsp;</p>', '&nbsp;' , '&nbsp' );
$blog_content = str_replace($replaceNbsp , ' ' , $request->blog_content);
```

This way, it replaces the versions wrapped in `<p>` tag *first*, THEN the `&nbsp;` without `<p>` tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get the paras containing just a non-breaking space *and the newline char that follows them* using this simple regex:

```
$blog_content = preg_replace('/<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\s*/', '', $request->blog_content);
```

Comment: @cale_b you are correct, although I suspect the OP doesn't *really* want to remove all the nbsps. They are actually useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this :

```
$replaceNbsp = array( '<p>&nbsp;</p>', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp' );
$blog_content = str_replace($replaceNbsp , ' ' , $request->blog_content);
return $blog_content;
```